# Repository, Pipeline, business logic and domain model - how do I fit these together?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm designing N-tier application and I came across a difficulty which you might have a solution to. Presentation layer is MVC.

My ORM is carried out using LinqToSQL - it's a seperate project which serves repositories.

Each reporsitory has an interface and at least 1 concrete implementation.

Repositories have the following methods: `FindAll(), Save(T entity), Delete(int id)`

`FindAll()` returns     IQueryable of some type, which means that it returns queries to which I can apply filters.

ORM mapping has been carried out using Database First methodology, where tables were created first and then classes were generated by SQL Metal.

I have added a Pipeline layer which works with repositories. It applies further filters to queries. E.g. `OrderRepository.FindAll().Where(o => o.CustomerId == 10)`

Pipeline also returns IQueryable of some type, which means that I can pass it further up the layer and do more stuff with it.

At this point I would like to move to the BusinessLogic layer, but I don't want to work with entity models any longer, I want to convert entity model to a domain model. This means that I can add validation to a model and use that model in the presentation layer. Model can't be defined in MVC project as it would be dependant on the presentation layer, so that's a no.

I'm fairly certain that business logic (behaviour) and model must be stored seperate from pipeline, data and presentation layer. The question is where?

For example, a pipeline has three methods:
1. FindByCustomerId
2. FindByOrderId
3. FindBySomethingElse

All these methods return IQueryable of Order. I need to convert this to a domain model, but I don't want to do it per each method as it won't be mainteinable.

I feel that this model is fairly robust and scalable. I just don't see what is the best place for mapping from entities to domain model and vise versa.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, if you are applying Domain Driven Design principles here, you must not have BusinessLogic layer in your application. All business logic should live inside your domain model.

But it is quite hard to achieve using LinqToSQL because it does not support inheritance mapping and you would have to deal with partial classes to put business logic into your domain. So I would strongly recommend to consider moving from LinqToSQL to NHibernate or Entity Framework Code First .In this case you also won't have to convert your persistence model into your domain model and vice versa.

If you still want to do conversion, you could take a look at [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm going to look into Entity Framework - I was under the impression that EF and LINQ-to-SQL are basically the same thing, where LINQ-To-SQL is a database first methodology.

Comment: I'm considering refactoring data layer to work with entity framework, but I'm worried that it might take too long. Additionally, there will be a learning curve of entity framework, wil have to re-write the majority of unit tests as they will have to work with domain model, rather than entity model.

Comment: I agree, but with a caveat: The _domain_ logic should reside in the domain models, but you might need to perform additional actions (_application logic_) when a certain domain model method is invoked. For example, you might want to notify a third party. To do so usually requires access to an `INotificationService`, and the domain models should not know about such a thing, I believe. Fowler makes this distinction between _domain logic_ and _application logic_, and suggests the second one should reside in the ServiceLayer - in this way, Domain Model and Service Layer play together well.

Comment: Sure, application logic should be separated from domain logic, but it shouldn't depend on domain model itself and should have dependency only on domain events. There is also some cross-cutting concerns that cannot be resolved at Domain layer. I use CQRS command and event handlers for such kinds of operations.

Answer (score 12):

From a domain driven point of view you would need a factory to convert your 'database entity' into a domain model entity.

When you're thinking of turning the 'database entities' to domain model entities at the end of your pipeline you should realize that after the conversion to domain model entities (a projection) you won't be able to use the IQueryable functionality as the projection will trigger execution of your expression tree. For example if you call FindAll for you customer database entity and then convert the IQueryable to (or project it onto) a customer domain entity it will execute (requesting the contents of your entire table).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. This is the main issue so far. I have to convert to domain model and then pass that model to the presentation layer. This works fine for data retrieval routines, but it falls on its arse when you start doing creating/updating data. I need to convert domain model back to the entity model, and so far I did not see an elegant way of doing this. As soon as it's converted to entity model, I then have to run create/update routine and convert it back to the domain model, which has been a nightmare so far.

Comment: Use of IQueryable and pipeline is great - I really like the pipeline. One of the ASP.Net storefrong videos has encouraged a use of LazyList, which is quite basic, but It doesn't seem to be right. Can't exactly justify why it's bad, but surely there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want your database entities and your domain model entities to be separate? This does create an abstraction but is there a need to do so now? Although it sounds to keep them separate this is something that can be added later (given a clean design)

Comment: Hi, at the moment I have a view model in a presentation layer, which 90% repeats a domain model. Another problem is that my business logic is not encapsulated. I'd like to have it in a seperate layer which would allow me to take business layer out of this app and use it in a different app. At the moment I can't do this since the logic is all over the place: model is in a data layer in form of Entities. Business methods are somewhat in a service layer. I have already mentioned view models. Also I find it difficult to write create/update routines for entities.

Comment: The project is getting bigger day by day. If I don't address these issues now, I'm afraid that I will face consequences later. By that time everything will be soo tightly coupled I won't be able to do much. Those are my concerns.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I do my N-Tier projects. This architecture has great separation of concerns. It sounds like you are already headed in this direction.

In the Mvc project is all your usual objects (Controllers, ViewModels, Views, helpers, etc). Fairly straight forward. All views are strongly typed. Plus my modified T4 templates that generate Controllers, Views, and ViewModels.

In the Business Model project I have all my business objects and rules, Included are the interfaces that define functionality of the data repositories. Instead of having one repository for every business object / table I prefer to group mine by functionality. All objects related to a blog are in one repository while all objects related to a photo gallery are in a separate repository, and logging may be in a third.

You could place your pipeline layer here.

In the Data project I implement those data repository interfaces. You can use Linq2SQL without having to use partial classes. Extending those Linq2SQL partial classes means you have tied your ORM to your domain model. Something you really don't want to do. You want to leave those generated data classes in the data domain. Here is an example Linq2SQL select that returns a BusinessModel object.

```
from t in Table
where t.Field == keyField
select new BusinessModel.DataObject
{
  Id = t.Id,
  Field1 = t.Field1,
  Field2 = t.Field2
}
```

If I were you I would look at EntityFramework 4.1 using the CodeFirst approach or use NHibernate. Either of these will map your data model to the domain model. Then to map the domain models to the view models you could use AutoMapper or write custom code or write a T4 template that would generate the mapping code for you.

You could take the code generated by the dbml file as a starting point for your business objects.

Comment: I just had another thought. Grab a copy of Subsonic and look at the ActiveRecord.tt file. It will show you how to generate class files from your database. It may be easier and faster than  stripping out a bunch of unnecessary code from the one generated by the DBML file.

Answer (score 3):

Further to xelibrion's comments you could have a look at LightSpeed for your ORM needs. You are currently using LinqToSQL so you should find Lightspeed very straight-forward since it uses the same idea.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed

If you can get your data to map Models that more match the form your higher levels want then hopefully you can simplify things. The less complexity in the system the less scope for bugs.

Answer (score 0):

> All these methods return IQueryable of
>   Order. I need to convert this to a
>   domain model, but I don't want to do
>   it per each method as it won't be
>   mainteinable.

This is not a true assessment and is probably blocking you from seeing the proper solution.

Comment: Care to expand on what about it is not true?  There's a few different statements in there.

Comment: IQuerable of Order is a query which has not been yet executed against the database, therefore I can apply further filters to this query in a pipeline. I would then call a ToList() or SingleOrDefault() on this query in order to get actual objects.

Comment: How many tables and models are you dealing with that it's becoming unmaintainable?

Comment: 17 tables. One of the tables is joined by another 4.